# What is the infamous "Archon Toilet"?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

I heard that expression quite a few times during casts, but what excatly is it and why is it called like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a tactic where a Mothership is used to phase out (vortex ability) the enemy army during an engagement. Following that, own archons are dropped into the vortex. When the skill ends, all units exit the portal in close proximity, and the auto-attack of the archons, coupled with their splash, wipes the enemy army.
The tactic has long since been nerfed, by making units exiting the field immune to damage for 1.5 seconds.

Comment: "this video is not available in your country..." :(

Comment: Search "archon toilet" and you'll probably get a hit. I get that too for some videos, but wow, I would never have thought anyone would block starcraft 2, of all things.

Comment: well.. i get that Archon part, but why "Toilet"?

Comment: Well Vortex is pretty spinny (flushing), I reckon that's where it came from. Enemy army goes down the drain, never to be seen again.